# Exception not triggered with try/catch/finally and stub method calls

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I am facing a PHPUnit issue in a Symfony2 context. I am testing the following method :

```
public function updatePassword(LdapUserInterface $user)
{
    $data = array();
    Attribute::setPassword($data, $user->getPassword(), Attribute::PASSWORD_UNICODEPWD);
    try {
        $this->ldap->bind();
        $this->ldap->update($user->getDn(), $data);
        return true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        throw new ConnectorException($this, 'Connector cannot connect to directory.');
    } finally {
        $this->ldap->disconnect();
    }
    return false;
}
```

I used the *finally* instruction PHP >5.5. My unitary test is ($this->logger references a stub defined in the *setUp* method):

```
/**
 * @expectedException UserBundle\Connectors\Exceptions\ConnectorException
 */
public function testUpdatePasswordException()
{
    $ldap = $this->getMockBuilder(Ldap::class)
                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                 ->setMethods(array('bind', 'disconnect', 'update'))
                 ->getMock();

    $ldap->method('update')->will($this->throwException(new LdapException($ldap, 'Fake Exception')));
    $user = $this->getMockBuilder(User::class)
                 ->setMethods(array('getDn', 'getPassword'))
                 ->getMock();
     $user->expects($this->once())->method('getPassword')->willReturn('#!12345mD');
     $user->expects($this->once())->method('getDn')->willReturn('cn=John Doe,ou=people,dc=athome.com,dc=com');

    $connector = new LdapConnector($this->logger, $ldap);
    $connector->updatePassword($user);
}
```

The UT did not trigger any exception and failed. Apparently, the problem comes from the *finally* instruction. Normally, the *disconnect* method is called once and that's why I added it into the stub. But, when I removed it, the test passes. 
While debugging, all instructions are called (try, catch, finally and then trigger of exception). I don't understand the behaviour of these, is it a php problem ? Seems not, so I wonder if there is not a problem with my *mock* or *phpunit*.

Any idea ?

Comment: It's not related to the question itself, but static methods in a test context triggers several alarms in my head. Tests should be [isolated](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UnitTestIsolation).

Comment: Now to your question: you say that your test fails. What is the reason it fails?

Comment: Are you dealing about *Ldap::class* ? I understood your answer but isn't the purpose of a *stub* ? To mock a dependency of the code ? So what should I do ? I thought my test was isolated, I tested one method of one class and stub all dependencies.

Comment: @henrique-barcelos The *ConnectorException* is not raised

Comment: Your stub is throwing a `LdapException`. Your test expects a `UserBundle\Connectors\Exceptions\ConnectorException`. Is the former a subtype of the latter?

Comment: My dependency **ldap**  is throwing **LdapException**, the catch method triggers **UserBundle\Connectors\Exceptions\ConnectorException**, so I think it's correct.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I'm trying to follow your code. A possible point of error is the instantiation of `LdapException`. Have you checked the constructor signature?

Comment: The signature is : `public function __construct(Ldap $ldap = null, $str = null, $code = 0)`, also correct, I guess.

Comment: I'm not trying to be annoying here, but when you said _"Apparently, the problem comes from the finally instruction. Normally, the disconnect method is called once and that's why I added it into the stub. But, when I removed **it**, the test passes"_, the **it** refers to the `finally` block or the stub method?

Comment: Sorry, I did not be accurate. It's into the stub :

+ `setMethods(array('bind', 'update', 'disconnect'))` does not pass the test.
+ `setMethods(array('bind', 'update'))` passes the test.

Comment: This is really odd. If you remove the stub method, it will raise and `E_ERROR` "Call to undefined method ..." because the `disconnect` method WILL BE called. Could you try tracing the execution with no `disconnect` method in the stub and show what you find?

Comment: Actually, you mis understood. If I remove `disconnect` method, the test passes (green) although the `disconnect` will be called as you and I said. But if I let it, the UT fails.

Comment: Sorry again, you are right. I was confused because the behavior of JUnit, that causes an error when you do not specify methods that will be mocked. PHPUnit actually calls the original method, with no replacing. If you don't call `setMethods` with `disconnect`, it will user your implementation on the `Ldap` class.

Comment: My last guess: try adding an execution constraint (like `once()`) on your stubbed methods and see how it behaves.

Comment: No effect with a simple `mock` of `bind` and `disconnect` method. By the way the official documentation says : *"By default, all methods of the original class are replaced with a dummy implementation that just returns null (without calling the original method)"*. So normally, that's not needed. See [Test Doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)

Comment: The docs also say: _"Please note that final, private and static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked. They are ignored by PHPUnit's test double functionality and retain their original behavior."_. Is this your case?

Comment: No, see [@zend-ldap](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-ldap/blob/release-2.5.1/src/Ldap.php). All these three methods are *public*.

Comment: Since  you're using [Zend\Ldap](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-ldap/blob/release-2.5.1/src/Ldap.php), it automatically calls the `disconnect` method in the destructor, you don't have to call it yourself. Will removing that call and the whole `finally` block make your test pass?

Comment: Yes it passes, but there is something not logical : the object is destruct after the whole method execution, not inside. And anyways, I can replace `disconnect` by another method like `getBoundUser` in my implementation of `updatePassword` and in my *stub*. The result is same, the UT does not pass. So it makes me think it's a problem of processing within PHPUnit and the call of `finally`.

Comment: Well, I find it strange that you are disconnecting from your LDAP server after executing one single operation, because resources are expensive to be obtained. Whenever you disconnect, you have to obtain a new connection when you try to do any other operation.

Anyways, just to be clear, are you telling me that if you replace your code with `finally {
        $this->ldap->getBoundUser();
    }` and then stub `getBoundUser` your test still fails?

Comment: I've tried to dig into `PHPUnit_Mock_Objects` but I was unable to find out if the problem is within the implementation or is some indiosincrasy of PHP `finally`. You should probably [open an issue](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues) to the maintainers of the package.

Comment: Yes I confirm the stub modif, with `getBounderUser` it's still not worked. By the way, you probably right for the pattern of connection/deconnection but there are one archi problem I don't know resolving :
I cannot *bind* at constructor method, because if there is a problem of network for instance, the service crashes at running and he is managed by the container. I have a set of connectors like that, a possible way is to create an `ìnit` method and initialize each object when I want to use the service, but it's not convinient. 
Thank you for your help, I will open an issue as you said.

Comment: Could you post the link when you open it? This issue is really intriguing me, I'd like to see the solution :)

Comment: I open the issue [here](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/issues/290).